# how to select an option from "attach" in message application using monkey runner

Tags: python, coordinates, mms, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am trying to automate sending of MMS using a monkey runner script which is a python script.I am getting the co-ordinates from hierarchy viewer for touch/press functions.But the problem is all these events work on the main screen.I mean if there is forground screen such as list of options that pops up when attachment option is selected in SMS window.How can i get co-ordinates or select such options.

```
from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

displayView = findViewWithAttribute('text:Pictures', 'Display')
#displayView.touch()
```

Here i am trying to select "Pictures" option and touch it but the code fails to work.Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to select this from the **Attach** dialog (Pictures, Capture picture, Videos, etc.). Please describe the steps you took and what you really expect.

Comment: yes,thats right.I need to attach picture from gallery and for this i need to select "Pictures".But the problem is that the script never selects the "pictures options" but selects the same co-ordinates on the background UI which is the compose message screen.I am trying to select "pictures" option which appears as a foreground screen.

Comment: Hey guys!!Any answers..?? struggling to find the solution..pls help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you open **MMS**, start a **New Message**, and then press **Attach**

[image]

when this dialog is displayed you run [culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/wiki/culebra) as

```
$ culebra -C -t on -o mms-attach.py
```

edit generated `mm-attach.py` to remove unneeded parts and add the `touch()` method. Your script would be something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env shebang monkeyrunner -plugin $ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME/bin/androidviewclient-$ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_VERSION.jar @!
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Copyright (C) 2013  Diego Torres Milano
Created on 2013-05-14 by Culebra v0.9.8

                      __    __    __    __
                     /  \  /  \  /  \  /  \ 
____________________/  __\/  __\/  __\/  __\_____________________________
___________________/  /__/  /__/  /__/  /________________________________
                   | / \   / \   / \   / \   \___
                   |/   \_/   \_/   \_/   \    o \ 
                                           \_____/--<
@author: Diego Torres Milano
@author: Jennifer E. Swofford (ascii art snake)
'''


import re
import sys
import os


from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice

device, serialno = ViewClient.connectToDeviceOrExit()
vc = ViewClient(device, serialno, autodump=False)
vc.dump(window='-1')

# unneeded views removed

# class=android.widget.TextView text="Pictures"
no_id14 = vc.findViewWithTextOrRaise('Pictures')
no_id14.touch()
```

you run it, and then **Pictures** is selected and now your are in the **Choose picture** screen as desired.